# How can I add a lead button to the approval history-related list

Tags: administration, approval-process, related-list, automation, developer

How can I add a lead button to the approval history-related list? Like, as we select approval requests, it's redirected to the all approval requests page. I have to add the lead option that redirected to the related records. (I need to add a new Column where we click and directly reach to the Lead.)[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can add button or customize approval history related list, Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdcFrUAJ/ability-to-customize-the-approval-history-related-list).

Workaround would be build custom page and add button on related list.